# Get site content over SSL with httr in R

Tags: r, ssl, apache2, rcurl, httr

I'm trying to fetch a JSON array from my server using the HTTP POST method in R.

I've tried using both the `POST`function from `httr`and the `getURL`function from `RCurl` but both return errors.

```
cafile <- system.file("CurlSSL", "cacert.pem", package = "RCurl")
url    <- "https://example.com/query/getData.php"

POST(url,body=NULL)
POST(url,body=NULL,config(cainfo=cafile))

getURL(url)
getURL(url,cainfo=cafile)
```

The error given by the `POST` function is (for both calls):

```
Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
  SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK
```

The error given by the `getURL` function is (without `config(cainfo=cafile)`):

```
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 162.xxx.xxx.xxx...
* connect to 162.xxx.xxx.xxx port 443 failed: Connection refused
*   Trying 130.yyy.yyy.yyy...
* Connected to example.com (130.yyy.yyy.yyy) port 443 (#0)
* found 175 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
* gnutls_handshake() warning: The server name sent was not recognized
* failed to get server cert
* Closing connection 0
Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
  gnutls_handshake() warning: The server name sent was not recognized
```

I'm suspecting this has something to do with R since running:

```
curl 'https://example.com/query/getData.php'
```

from the command line return the expected result.

The server is a apache2 server with COMODO SSL certificate.
In  `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf` the server name is set to

```
ServerName www.example.com
```

Any help would be most apreciated

Comment: My guess is that R is not trusting the cert coming from `example.com`.  To remedy this, you will need to add this cert to your trust store.

Comment: Shouldn't R trust the certificate if the certificate is trusted when browsing the site in a web-browser, I've also verified the certificate online? Is the trust store R specific?

Comment: Yes, I would expect this.  Can you try manually adding the base 64 encoded cert to your `cacert.pem` file?  Yes, this is a hack but it will let us see what is going on.

Comment: I've tried this but I'm getting the same error, (i don't have a .pem file but I have .ca-bundle, .crt, .p7b .csr and .key files and I've tried with all of them). I tried the same command with the verbose option set to true so I'll edit my question to include this.

Comment: Can it be that the certificate and the server returns different server names?

Comment: Your code implies that you have a file called `cacert.pem`.  Is this not the case?  This is the cause of your woes.  R cannot verify the cert which `example.com` is sending back.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96139/discussion-between-oskar-forsmo-and-tim-biegeleisen).

Comment: `download.file(url="http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem", destfile="cacert.pem")`  ... you need to get a truststore file.

Comment: Same error `gnutls_handshake() warning: The server name sent was not recognized`

Comment: removing the www part from ServerName resolved this, I'm not sure if it's in combination with updating cacert.pem. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Please look into this and then answer your own question.

Answer (score 4):

The `httr` package includes it's own CA bundle so this probably not the issue. More likely a server side SNI config problem or a problem with your certificate

Unfortunately you haven't posted a reproducible example with an actual URL. But with the latest version of the new openssl package you can easily debug your server cert:

```
library(openssl)
cert <- download_ssl_cert("www.r-project.org")
print(cert)
print(as.list(cert[[1]]))
```

Also try validating it

```
cert_verify(cert, ca_bundle())
```

This might give a hint on what's wrong with your certificate.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I didn't want to disclose the domain name of my server though. It seems like this was a problem with the server setup.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like changing

```
ServerName www.example.com
```

To

```
ServerName example.com
```

fixed this issue. I tried this solution from another computer and I was able to use the httr POST function with this fix with the default httr CA bundle.