# SSL connect error in httr / curl

Tags: r, httr

I'm trying to access an open API with `httr`, and having no luck. Whenever I try:

```
httr::GET("https://api.openaq.org/v1/countries")
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
   SSL connect error
```

However, other connections to https work just fine, for example

```
httr::GET("https://httpbin.org/get")
```

Here is the output of `sessionInfo()`:

```
R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_CA.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_CA.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_CA.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_CA.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_CA.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_CA.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_CA.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[7] base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] httr_1.0.0.9000 R6_2.1.2        tools_3.2.3     curl_0.9.5
```

At terminal, if I run `curl-config --version` I get

```
libcurl 7.35.0
```

#### updates: things I have tried

- confirmed that this is the most recent version of libcurl3 for Ubuntu 14.04
- checked the ssl certificate using `openssl` as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33917311/1727133)
- uninstalled/reinstalled `curl`, `RCurl` and `httr`
- confirmed that this *DOES* work from the terminal:

`curl -v "https://api.openaq.org/v1/countries"`

I cannot understand how the command-line curl works fine, but `curl` in R fails

### more updates -- `verbose` doesn't work

I've tried getting more info from R by asking `httr` to be verbose. It produces the identical error:

`httr::GET("https://api.openaq.org/v1/countries", httr::verbose())
Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
  SSL connect error`

same with `httr::GET("https://api.openaq.org/v1/countries", httr::verbose(ssl=TRUE))`

Comment: I've just ran into this problem too. Using curl at the command line seems to work fine, but not from R. According to `curl_version()` I'm using version 7.22.0.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Is this error still occurring?

Comment: I suspect SSLv3 problem. Can you please include output of  `curl::curl_fetch_memory("https://api.openaq.org/v1/countries", new_handle(verbose=T))`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The SSL handshake fails. Some potential reasons:

- You compiled with gnutls instead of openssl. Try: `apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev`.
- Your libcurl is really outdated and does not support the TLS version required by the server.

Comment: Yes, I can confirm it's due to some issue with using GnuTLS instead of OpenSSL. The problem occurred on my laptop with curl package 0.9.5 and curl version 7.22.0, where `curl_version()$ssl_version` shows it's using GnuTLS/2.12.14. It all seems OK on another machine with the same curl package and version, but where OpenSSL/1.0.1 is used. I wonder why.

Answer (score 10):

Solved this (with assistance from @Jeroen and [richfitz](https://github.com/richfitz/))

First I ran the following in the terminal:

`sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev`

then uninstalled and reinstalled `curl` in R:

`install.packages("curl")`

Comment: Thank you, it helped me.

Answer (score 6):

I'm using R-4.3.1 and work in a corporate network with SSL intercept. I encountered this 'SSL connect error' and reverted to using install.packages("some_package", method="wininet"). While wininet works, it is a bit slow. Here's my new workaround:

- Removed the wininet workaround to revert back to the default libcurl
- Added the following line to my .Rprofile

  - Sys.setenv(R_LIBCURL_SSL_REVOKE_BEST_EFFORT=TRUE)

I learnt this via the following references:

- https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/10163#issuecomment-1193316767
- https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/10163#issuecomment-1207356113

I hope this helps!

Comment: Great this resolved my issue ! thanks