# Installation error for the BiocManager, dada2 and MicrobiotaProcess package in RStudio

Tags: r, bioconductor

I'm a recent user of R in RStudio and I'm having difficulty installing some packages. **The version of R I'm using is R 4.3.1**, and **RStudio 2023.3.2.454**. My operating system is Windows 7.
I can't install the BiocManager, DADA2 and MicrobiotaProcess packages. Everyone is giving an error when trying to install or run.
I am unable to install the BiocManager, DADA2 and MicrobiotaProcess packages. Everyone is giving an error when trying to install or run. BiocManager says that the version cannot be validated, as if I had no internet connection, but I am properly connected. The DADA2 and MicrobiotaProcess packages state that A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at: "https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages".

When requesting the command:

```
install.packages("BiocManager")
```

I receive as a message:

```
Installing package into 'C:/Users/Petronio/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.3' (as 'lib' is unspecified) trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/ 4.3/BiocManager_1.30.22.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 495547 bytes (483 KB)
downloaded 483 KB package ‘BiocManager’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
The downloaded binary packages are in
C:\Users\Petronio\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpOKdPaS\downloaded_packages
```

However, when running the library

```
library(BiocManager)
```

I receive the following message:

```
Bioconductor version cannot be validated; no internet connection? See #troubleshooting section in vignette

Warning messages:
1: In file(con, "r") :
URL 'https://bioconductor.org/config.yaml': status was 'SSL connect error'
2: In file(con, "r") :
URL 'https://bioconductor.org/config.yaml': status was 'SSL connect error'
```

The same error appears when requesting the installation of the DADA2 and MPSE packages.

```
install.packages("dada2")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Petronio/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.3’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages:
   package ‘dada2’ is not available for this version of R

A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages

install.packages("MicrobiotaProcess")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Petronio/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.3’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages:
   package ‘MicrobiotaProcess’ is not available for this version of R

A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages
```

Please help me. I do not know what else to do. I've already tried manual installation, installation via zip file and the command:

```
remotes::install_github("url")
```

However, without success. I don't know what else I could do. If you can help me I will be extremely grateful.

Comment: Does `readLines("https://bioconductor.org/config.yaml")` work? If not you may be behind a proxy.  [Source](https://support.bioconductor.org/p/125812/).

Comment: Error in file(con, "r") : 
  cannot open the connection to 'https://bioconductor.org/config.yaml'
In addition: Warning message:
In file(con, "r") :
  URL 'https://bioconductor.org/config.yaml': status was 'SSL connect error'

Comment: I have the same problem today. Have you solved it?

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76684292/163080) works for me: `Sys.setenv(R_LIBCURL_SSL_REVOKE_BEST_EFFORT=TRUE)`

Comment: I ended up needing to buy another machine (notebook) to be able to carry out my analyses. Apparently this error message appears when the machine does not support the package. This may be related to the system version, the R version or even the machine's memory sufficiency for the package's performance.